# Typescript/Javascript can't find module

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to install a module named "request" https://github.com/request/request

in my angular 2 typescript project but I can't get it imported for some reason.

I tried installing the normal way with npm install --save request and I tried typings install request --ambient --save aswell although I don't know what exactly that does anyway.

I'm working off of this boilerplate https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed which in the wiki suggests that install modules is as easy as using npm install and then

```
 import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
```

But I can't import my request module for some Reason.

This is my import line

```
import * as request from 'request';
```

Do I need to reference the module elsewhere somehow?

Comment: did you do **npm install** ?

Comment: `typings` is for definition files. Did you try installing it using `npm install request`?

Comment: yes I did npm install. I didn't mention that because I thought it was obvious

Answer (score 2):

The `request` module isn't designed for browsers only for Node applications. You should use the `browser-request` instead.

That being said, installing the module with NPM isn't directly usable into your application:

- **For compilation** you need to install a typing for compilation. A kind of contract of the API of your library. This way the TypeScript compilation will know which classes, methods and properties are present in the module.
- **For execution** you need to reference your module when loading your application. For example with SystemJS you need something like that:

  ```
  System.config({
    map: {
      request: 'node_modules/browser-request/index.js'
    }
  });
  ```

  This way you will be able to import the library this way:

  ```
  import * as request from 'request';
  ```